# Generating odoo report on the basis of active records

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I am using following function to fetch records in my report.

```
def get_records(self):
    recsss = self.pool.get('overtime_oms_bcube.overtime_oms_bcube').search(self.cr,self.uid, [], context=self.context)
    resss = self.pool.get('overtime_oms_bcube.overtime_oms_bcube').browse(self.cr, self.uid, recsss)
    return resss
```

and calling the records by following way:

```
<t t-set="i" t-value="1"/>
<tr t-foreach="get_records()" t-as="data">

    <td style="display:none">
        <t t-esc="i"/>
        <t t-set="i" t-value="i+1"/>
    </td>

    <td t-esc="data['employee_code']"></td>
    <td t-esc="data['employee'].name"></td>
    <td t-esc="data['employee'].job_id.name"></td>
    <td t-esc="data['no_of_days']"></td>
    <td t-esc="data['employee'].contract_id.wage"></td>
    <td t-esc="data['employee'].contract_id.wage*0.64516129"></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that the resulting report is showing all the records saved in the data base. I want it to show only those records which are selected in the tree view. As you see the active/selected records in the image below.

[image]And even in if we are in the single record view and generate a report, it still shows all the record but according to the flow it need to generate a report of that record from where we are generating that report.

please suggest something that helps in such requirement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get to call the function get_records(), I always get the nonetype error whenever I call a function from qweb without the o. in front. Or can you maybe provide your full xml code? thanks Jesse

Comment: dont call t-foreach t-as=o on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relace this code:

```
def get_records(self):
    recsss = self.pool.get('overtime_oms_bcube.overtime_oms_bcube').search(self.cr,self.uid, [], context=self.context)
    resss = self.pool.get('overtime_oms_bcube.overtime_oms_bcube').browse(self.cr, self.uid, recsss)
    return resss
```

withe the following

```
def get_records(self):
  active_ids =  self.context.get('active_ids',False)
  recsss = self.pool.get('overtime_oms_bcube.overtime_oms_bcube').search(self.cr,self.uid, [('id','in',active_ids)], context=self.context)
  resss = self.pool.get('overtime_oms_bcube.overtime_oms_bcube').browse(self.cr, self.uid, recsss)
  return resss
```

It will generate the active Ids only. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Create Wizard 
[Example of odoo default product pricelist report wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfcX4.png)

[Click on Print button system will call wizard print method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oxNh.png)

Step: 2: Create Print method in Wizard

```
def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """
    To get the date and print the report
    @return : return report
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    datas = {'ids': context.get('active_ids', [])}
    res = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['price_list','qty1', 'qty2','qty3','qty4','qty5'], context=context)
    res = res and res[0] or {}
    res['price_list'] = res['price_list'][0]
    datas['form'] = res
    return self.pool['report'].get_action(cr, uid, [], 'product.report_pricelist', data=datas, context=context)
```

**In The Context you will get active ids and get_action method will print report**

Comment: we create a widget. why we need to go in that long procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if `active_ids` is present in `context` when calling your method. If it is present, just use the IDs for your browse() call.